# Method / Class validating a pkpass (passbook pass) in PassKitCore on iOS 10

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet

My title is rather self-explanatory. There is something validating a passbook pass when clicked on a pkpass attached to an email for example. If the signature is not valid, the pass doesn't even show.

Anyone having some knowledge about the PassKitCore methods ?

Comment: Are you trying to validate a pass using an API call or understand why your pass doesn't load when opened via email?

Comment: No I am not trying to validate a pass sing an API nor understanding why the pass doesn't load. I know the pass doesn't load because the signature is not valid so my question is simple: Does anyone knows which method is checking the signature in PassKitCore ?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't able to open your pass on an iPhone, plug the iPhone into a Mac and open the 'Console' application. On the left, you can select your iPhone. You will then be able to inspect any errors that occur while adding the pass.

Comment: Thank you, but as you showed, it says "Signature Validation Failed" without giving a method checking the signature. Unless it all happens in "initWithData" from PkPass in the middle of your screenshot.

On jailbroken devices, Appsync allows to install unsigned/fakesigned apps, so it should be possible to create/find a tweak that allows to load unsigned/fakesigned passes...

Comment: @Ultinio its just sample screenshot how to debug device with mac. I removed screenshot.